# How to pass in negative numbers for specflow example in a scenario outline?

Tags: nunit, specflow

I have this feature

```
Feature: Selling Holiday
    As a person selling holiday
    I want to know the bonus per month

Scenario Outline: Selling Holiday
    Given I am selling holiday
    And I have a current salary rate of <rate> pounds an hour
    And I have chosen <hours> hours
    Then the cost should be <cost>

Examples: 
    | rate  | hours | cost  |
    | 9.00  | 14    | -10.2 |
    | 12.00 | 14    | -14   |
    | 8.0   | 7.5   | -5    |
```

---

```
[Then]
public void Then_the_cost_should_be_COST(decimal cost)
{
    //Cost is always positive :(
    Assert.AreEqual(cost, holidayCostCalculator.CalculateCost();
}
```

The problem is that cost is getting passed into the steps as positive not negative as I have stated.

There's another question on here where they solved it by adding an attribute but this is not an acceptable solution in my mind as it's not at all intuitive.

Comment: if it's not coming through then it sounds like it might be a bug. What version (nuget and extension) are you using? It might be worth raising an issue at github, I might be able to look at it in the next few days. As a workaround you can probably make this step use a regex in the attribute temporarily.

Comment: My extension is `2015.1.2` and the nuget version is `1.9`. I just found an issue that's open, but it might be stale as it's been open since 2012. https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/246. I'm happy to open a new one if it helps.

Comment: seems like the same issue. Seeing as you have updated the extension already, you could try the v2 nuget beta build from https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/specflow-ci just in case it has magically fixed itself.

Comment: Just tried it with the v2 source and it's the same issue I'm afraid.

Comment: ok, great. Thanks. I'll try and have a look.

Answer (score 4):

use the traditional step style

```
[Then(@"the cost should be (.*)")]
public void ThenTheCostShouldBe(Decimal cost)
{
}
```

Also to avoid input string issues remove trailing zeros from values in the table:

```
| rate | hours | cost  |
| 9    | 14    | -10.2 |
| 12   | 14    | -14   |
| 8    | 7     | -5    |
```

Answer (score 0):

[PR submitted](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/623) to fix this issue. It should make the 2.1 release which is scheduled for a couple of weeks I believe.